# Comparison of criterion in choosing Saul and David as kings

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, samuel-shmuel-book-of, king-david, king-saul

In reading some of the vesres explaining a criterion in choosing Saul and David as kings, I found:

In [I Samuel 9:2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14258&st=&pgnum=66), Saul is described as being tall and good looking. G-d doesn't seem to object to this criteria in any way and Saul becomes king.

Yet, when Samuel chooses a successor for Saul, he vies several of Jesse's sons, and G-d "chastises" Samuel and says in [I Samuel 16:7](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14258&st=&pgnum=131) **not** to look at the person's features or height.

Yet, we see that at the end, when G-d chooses David, he was described as good looking ([ibid 16:12](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14258&st=&pgnum=133)).

Questions:

Did G-d change his criterion between Saul and David? If so, why?

Regarding David, G-d says not to look at his features, yet, he chose someone with good features. Is this contradictory?

Comment: Not paying attention to looks doesn't mean picking someone short and ugly. That would be paying attention to appearance!

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm missing a nuance in your comment. It seems like "looks" and "appearance" mean the same thing.

Comment: I agree they mean the same thing. I didn't intend to distinguish them.